# React App Error: Cannot find module 'react-error-overlay/middleware'

Tags: reactjs

This is very frustrating.  I've been dealing with this issue since yesterday morning.  I have a React application I have not started up in over a year.  This application ran perfectly last time I started it up.  But I want to work on it locally, and using the exact same package.json when it ran just fine a year ago, is failed in the browser with the following error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'ReactCurrentOwner' of undefined
```

Since the package.json was a year old, today I ran npm update and when I try and run the program I receive the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'react-error-overlay/middleware'
```

Old package.json

```
{
  "name": "mazzo-react-test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "auth0-lock": "^10.24.3",
    "autoprefixer": "7.1.2",
    "babel-core": "6.25.0",
    "babel-eslint": "7.2.3",
    "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "7.1.1",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^3.1.2",
    "babel-runtime": "6.23.0",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.1.1",
    "chalk": "^1.1.3",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "dotenv": "4.0.0",
    "eslint": "4.4.1",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^2.1.0",
    "eslint-loader": "1.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.35.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "5.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.1.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "0.11.2",
    "fs-extra": "3.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.29.0",
    "jest": "20.0.4",
    "konva": "^1.7.6",
    "material-ui": "^0.18.7",
    "object-assign": "4.1.1",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "3.2.0",
    "postcss-loader": "2.0.6",
    "promise": "8.0.1",
    "react": "^15.6.2",
    "react-dev-utils": "^3.1.3",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.2",
    "react-error-overlay": "^1.0.10",
    "react-konva": "^1.7.16",
    "react-relay": "0.10.0",
    "react-relay-network-layer": "1.3.9",
    "react-router": "3.0.2",
    "react-router-relay": "0.13.5",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "relay-commit-mutation-promise": "^1.0.1",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "styled-components": "^2.4.1",
    "sw-precache-webpack-plugin": "0.11.4",
    "url-loader": "0.5.9",
    "webpack": "3.5.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.7.1",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "1.2.1",
    "whatwg-fetch": "2.0.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT=https://api.graph.cool/relay/v1/cj63i9kajpzhw0153segab1wa node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js --env=jsdom"
  },
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx}"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/config/polyfills.js"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.js?(x)",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/?(*.)(spec|test).js?(x)"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "testURL": "http://localhost",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx)$"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "web.js",
      "js",
      "json",
      "web.jsx",
      "jsx",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "babel": {
    "plugins": [
      "react-relay"
    ],
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-react-relay": "^0.10.0"
  }
}
```

New or updated package.json

```
    {
  "name": "mazzo-react-test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "auth0-lock": "^11.14.0",
    "autoprefixer": "9.4.7",
    "babel-core": "6.26.3",
    "babel-eslint": "10.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "24.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "8.0.5",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^7.0.1",
    "babel-runtime": "6.26.0",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.2.0",
    "chalk": "^2.4.2",
    "css-loader": "2.1.0",
    "dotenv": "6.2.0",
    "eslint": "5.14.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^3.0.7",
    "eslint-loader": "2.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "3.4.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.12.4",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "3.0.1",
    "fs-extra": "7.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "3.2.0",
    "jest": "24.1.0",
    "konva": "^2.6.0",
    "material-ui": "^0.20.2",
    "object-assign": "4.1.1",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "4.1.0",
    "postcss-loader": "3.0.0",
    "promise": "8.0.2",
    "react": "^16.8.2",
    "react-dev-utils": "^7.0.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.2",
    "react-error-overlay": "^5.1.3",
    "react-konva": "^16.8.2-0",
    "react-relay": "2.0.0",
    "react-relay-network-layer": "2.2.1",
    "react-router": "4.3.1",
    "react-router-relay": "0.14.0",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^3.0.3",
    "relay-commit-mutation-promise": "^1.0.0",
    "style-loader": "0.23.1",
    "styled-components": "^4.1.3",
    "sw-precache-webpack-plugin": "0.11.5",
    "url-loader": "1.1.2",
    "webpack": "4.29.5",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.1.14",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "2.0.4",
    "whatwg-fetch": "3.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT=https://api.graph.cool/relay/v1/cj63i9kajpzhw0153segab1wa node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js --env=jsdom"
  },
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx}"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/config/polyfills.js"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.js?(x)",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/?(*.)(spec|test).js?(x)"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "testURL": "http://localhost",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx)$"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "web.js",
      "js",
      "json",
      "web.jsx",
      "jsx",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "babel": {
    "plugins": [
      "react-relay"
    ],
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-react-relay": "^0.10.0"
  }
}
```

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you're running into is the way that `npm` modules work - this issue that you're having isn't exclusive to `react`. We can't be expected to solve this for you - but I can try to point you in the right direction.

I'll use the dependency in your `package.json` as an example, the line:
`"react-error-overlay": "^1.0.10"` has a caret (`^`) next to the version number.

This means when you run `npm install` in most cases, or `npm update` then `npm` will go grab the **most recent** version of that package, above that version number.

If you compare the two different `package.json` files in your post you will notice that there are multiple major package versions skipped for quite a few of your dependencies. If you look up **semantic versioning** you'll find that a major version bump usually is due to a **breaking change** in the module.

E.g:
Old: `"react-error-overlay": "^1.0.10"`
New: `"react-error-overlay": "^5.1.3"`

In here you are jumping from major version `1.x.x` to `5.x.x`. That is over 4 breaking changes for just this module alone.

Basically, this means that the module does not work in the same way it did before. If you project worked a year or so ago - and you ran `npm update` - it most likely will fail now as you're pulling in new major package versions.

If you just want your project to work as it did before, here is what I recommend:

Take the original version of your `package.json` and remove the `^` carets in the version numbers.
Then clear out your `node_modules` folder in your project.
Then run `npm install`.


This should pull in the module versions very similar to what you were working with before. Try and see if it runs then. If it does, update your dependencies individually from there - and find which major version bumps cause your project to break.

**Also:**
As for the typeError you are getting - it stems from `react-konva` as noted in this issue thread:
https://github.com/konvajs/react-konva/issues/147#issuecomment-346217504

`react-konva` above version `1.1.6` is for `react` v16 and above

Target `react v15` by using the version:
`"react-konva": "1.1.6"`

Comment: Thank you.  I really appreciate you.  Now I can move on to other things like eating and showering...Have a good one.